# Tag change: [cut-command] -> [cut]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tag [cut-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cut-command) should be called [cut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cut). Many other commands, including [cp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cp), [mv](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mv) are not with the suffix `-command`.

Please could we have [cut-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cut-command) changed to [cut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cut).

Firstly, all the questions should be edited to change [cut-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cut-command) to [cut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cut).

Then, [cut-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cut-command) should be made a synonym of [cut](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cut).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not in favour of this. The command names of `cp` and `mv` are sufficiently different from their actions (copy, move) that the `-command` suffix is not needed to make it unambiguous. But this is not true for `cut`, where an action has the same name as the command.  This also holds for `watch`. I do a fair bit of retag edits and I have seen plenty of people just use words in the question as tags, and this risks increasing misuses of [cut-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cut-command) or [watch-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/watch-command) in questions that involve cutting or watching of some sort, but entirely unrelated to the commands themselves.

Comment: Thanks @muru. This helps.

Comment: Note: I've copied your answer to the `watch`-related tag merge request as well, so the same answer is available at both.