# Tag change: [watch-command] -> [watch]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

The tag [watch-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/watch-command) should be called [watch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/watch). Many other commands, including [cp](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cp), [mv](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/mv) are not with the suffix `-command`.

Please could we have [watch-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/watch-command) changed to [watch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/watch).

Firstly, all the questions should be edited to change [watch-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/watch-command) to [watch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/watch).

Then, [watch-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/watch-command) should be made a synonym of [watch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/watch).

Comment: see [muru’s answer](https://meta.askubuntu.com/a/17907/507051) on the [tag:cut-command] → [tag:cut] proposal

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer from muru [on another tag change/merge proposal posted around the same time](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/17904/tag-change-cut-command-cut) is also relevant here, as the same reasoning is also applied to the `watch` tag in their answer/reasoning:

> I'm not in favour of this. The command names of `cp` and `mv` are sufficiently different from their actions (copy, move) that the `-command` suffix is not needed to make it unambiguous. But this is not true for `cut`, where an action has the same name as the command.  This also holds for `watch`. I do a fair bit of retag edits and I have seen plenty of people just use words in the question as tags, and this risks increasing misuses of [cut-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/cut-command) or [watch-command](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/watch-command) in questions that involve cutting or watching of some sort, but entirely unrelated to the commands themselves.